# How to parameterize TestFixtureSetUp (NUnit)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nunit, automated-tests

In my test the next flow takes place:

1. I do some actions (for example buy a product) before all tests are run
2. Then in each test I check one assertion

I use NUnit framework to run test so I use [TestFixtureSetUp] to mark a set of actions that are done once before all tests. Then I use [Test] or [TestCase()] to run tests.

Often it happens that I need to check the same things but perform different flow. So I have to parameterize [TestFixtureSetUp]. Can I somehow do it?

**So I want to make my set of actions that is performed once before all tests depended on parameters.**

If it's possible to do with different frameworks or different flow structure please tell me)

**Example of my code:**

```
 [TestFixtureSetUp] //This will be done once before all tests
 public void Buy_Regular_One_Draw_Ticket(WayToPay merchant)
 {
          //here I want to do some actions and use different merchants to pay. 

          //So how can I send different parameters to this method?

 }
```

Comment: an example would greatly help to understand, what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: Sure thing) Thanks for a clue)

Answer (score 3):

**Guys the solution is the next:** constructor of the class runs before [TestFixtureSetUp] so all actions that were made in [TestFixtureSetUp] now are made in the constructor of a class.

And we have an ability to send parameters to the constructor! For this we use [TestFixture()].

**The whole code is the next:**

```
[TestFixture(WaysToPay.Offline)]
[TestFixture(WaysToPay.Neteller)]
public class DepositTests
{
        //Constructor takes parameters from TestFixture
        public DepositTests(WaysToPay merchant) 
        {
            //Do actions before tests considering your parameters
        }

        [Test]
        public void Your_test_method()
        {
            //do your verification here
        }
    }
```

**Using this approach instead of using [TestFixtureSetUp] you can make your tests more flexible. So the behavior is the same as if [TestFixtureSetUp] can get parameters**.